# In a select statement, the buffer in channel will be used firstly or the pending queue value will be used firstly?

Tags: go

Recently I've been reading the source code of `select` in Go. There is some part of the code that I don't understand.

For example, when the channel being selected has a pending send operation, or a pending receive operation, it first uses the value from pending send instead of the value in channel buffer.

```
// pass 1 - look for something already waiting
    var dfli int
    var dfl *scase
    var casi int
    var cas *scase
    var recvOK bool
    for i := 0; i < ncases; i++ {
        casi = int(pollorder[i])
        cas = &scases[casi]
        c = cas.c

        switch cas.kind {
        case caseNil:
            continue

        case caseRecv:
            sg = c.sendq.dequeue()
            if sg != nil {
                goto recv
            }
            if c.qcount > 0 {
                goto bufrecv
            }
            if c.closed != 0 {
                goto rclose
            }

        case caseSend:
            if raceenabled {
                racereadpc(c.raceaddr(), cas.pc, chansendpc)
            }
            if c.closed != 0 {
                goto sclose
            }
            sg = c.recvq.dequeue()
            if sg != nil {
                goto send
            }
            if c.qcount < c.dataqsiz {
                goto bufsend
            }

        case caseDefault:
            dfli = casi
            dfl = cas
        }
    }
```

So I wrote some simple code to verify my assumption. But the result implies I'm wrong.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var mark chan int
    length := 3
    c := make(chan int, length)
    for i := 1; i <= length; i++ {
        c <- i
    }

    go func() {
        c <- 4
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)
    select {
    case val := <-c:
        fmt.Println("receive val is ", val)
    case _ = <-mark:
        fmt.Println("block chan")
    }
}
```

The result is `receive val is  1`. However, I think the printed output should be `receive val is  4`. It seems that the `select` first uses value in buffer.

Answer (score 3):

You read the source code wrong.

The code `goto recv` goes to a code block labelled `recv`, which is:

```
recv:
    // can receive from sleeping sender (sg)
    recv(c, sg, cas.elem, func() { selunlock(scases, lockorder) }, 2)
    if debugSelect {
        print("syncrecv: cas0=", cas0, " c=", c, "\n")
    }
    recvOK = true
    goto retc
```

And if you look in `recv` function (https://golang.org/src/runtime/chan.go#L607), which is defined in `channel.go`, you would see it read from the buffer if there is one. From the document of that function:

```
// recv processes a receive operation on a full channel c.
// There are 2 parts:
// 1) The value sent by the sender sg is put into the channel
//    and the sender is woken up to go on its merry way.
// 2) The value received by the receiver (the current G) is
//    written to ep.
// For synchronous channels, both values are the same.
// For asynchronous channels, the receiver gets its data from
// the channel buffer and the sender's data is put in the
// channel buffer.
// Channel c must be full and locked. recv unlocks c with unlockf.
// sg must already be dequeued from c.
// A non-nil ep must point to the heap or the caller's stack.
```

To conclude it, the case in question is just to see if there is a sender waiting on it, which means either due to the channel is unbufferred or the buffer of the channel is full; and it has nothing to do what value the receiver is receiving.

Answer (score 2):

Your `mark` channel is not initialized [1], so it will never be ready, therefore never chosen in the `select` statement. Otherwise, when multiple `case`s are available at the same time, the `select` statement chooses one of them at random.

Furthermore you don't even send anything on `mark`, but if you attempted that, the send operation would block, as there can't be any receiver for a `nil` channel anyway.

If no `case` is ready, and *there is* a `default` case, the default is selected, otherwise it blocks.

Please check also the [tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5).

---

[1] a `var` declaration will leave `mark` to its zero value, which is `nil`.